# Is there a Mizar-like sublanguage for Coq?

Tags: coq, software-request, mizar

[Isabelle](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/) has the frontend [Isar](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/Isar/) which mimics some features of the [Mizar system](http://mizar.org/).

I'm curious if [Coq](https://coq.inria.fr/) has anything similar, i.e. an alternative to tactic scripts that's designed to be readable or similar to the mathematical vernacular.

[This discussion](https://coq.discourse.group/t/are-there-any-declarative-proof-languages-for-coq/825) on the Coq forums mentions Czar and SSReflect.

Comment: Yeah, Corbineau wrote Czar as documented in his paper, [A Declarative Language For The Coq Proof Assistant](https://kluedo.ub.uni-kl.de/frontdoor/deliver/index/docId/2100/file/B-065.pdf).

It fell into disuse, and was removed in Coq 8.7. I was disappointed to see its departure.

Since then, there hasn't been an adequate replacement.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There indeed used to be a "declarative language for Coq" often referred to as Czar, but it was removed (from Coq's core) a long time ago. If it had had any actual users, it would have been easy at the time to restore it as an external plugin though.

Having tested it when it was still there, my personal impression was that it was actually very difficult to use, and nowhere near what Isar has achieved for Isabelle. My understanding is that one of the main reason why Isar was so successful is thanks to SledgeHammer.

Fortunately today, Coq has [CoqHammer](https://coqhammer.github.io/) (which is even available as part of the [Coq Platform](https://github.com/coq/platform/releases)). Furthermore, Coq's tactics are pretty flexible for different styles. So, with a combination of tactics such as [`assert`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.assert), [`enough`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacv.enough), [`now_show`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proofs/writing-proofs/equality.html#coq:tacn.now_show), and CoqHammer tactics, it is actually possible to reconstruct the Isar style in Coq (no need for a specific proof mode for this).

Another declarative-style set of tactic is provided by the [`coq-waterproof`](https://github.com/impermeable/coq-waterproof) package (see an example in their README). The proof style looks very much like mathematical text. However, while Czar was suffering from a lack of IDE support (it's almost impossible to remember exactly how to write a "natural language" proof in what is in fact a controlled language), `coq-waterproof` is a support package for the [Waterproof IDE](https://github.com/impermeable/waterproof) (which is targeted at students). So this might be close to what you are looking for, but for pedagogical purposes. If the goal is to reproduce the Isar style with productivity in mind, then I would still rather recommend relying on Coq's tactics like `assert` and `enough` + CoqHammer.

Finally, SSReflect was also mentioned. It is in fact very different from a declarative mode because it is very "procedural". However, the style in which SSReflect users write their proof is supposed to be close to the style of proofs in mathematical texts (one line per significant mathematical step) and reliance on the `have:` tactic to clarify the most important steps. The main difference between the SSReflect style and the Isar style is that SSReflect only relies on very small-scale automation, making the proofs in SSReflect very robust to evolution in the underlying Coq language, libraries or specifications.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the strategy "`assert` + CoqHammer $\approx$ Mizar-like input language" being a good idea. It's more a kludge.

Comment: Note that I'm comparing to Isar here, not to Mizar. I have no idea what Mizar used to be like, if it was a practical or productive system. But I know that Isar is a productive system in large part thanks to SledgeHammer.

Comment: Sorry, when you wrote, "If the goal is to reproduce the Izar style..." it was difficult to tell if you meant Mizar or Isar. But, (a) [Mizar](http://mizar.org/) is still active and flourishing, and (b) regardless whether  you meant Isar or Mizar, the `assert` + CoqHammer strategy still feels like a kludge.

Comment: I've fixed the typo and added some more content (it's not just `assert`, it's also `enough` and a few other tactics that can help). My point is mostly that the Coq tactic system is flexible and you do not need an entirely different proof mode to adopt this style.